# MySQL: Shouldn't this return more rows?

Tags: mysql, search, sql-like

I'm running a simple LIKE search on a table but i can't seem to get more than one result for some reason. In the query example below i include words like "never back down" and "soul surfer" but i only get one of the movies. I have those movies in my database, along with many others.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT movies . * , GROUP_CONCAT( categories.name ) AS categories, GROUP_CONCAT( categories.id ) AS categories_id
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN movies_categories ON ( movies.id = movies_categories.movie_id ) 
LEFT JOIN categories ON ( movies_categories.category_id = categories.id ) 
WHERE movies.movie_title LIKE  '%surfer%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%date%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%never%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%back%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%down%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%surfer%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%soul%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%the%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%transporter%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I was thinking there must be something wrong with the query, otherwise it would return all results? I am aware some of the words are duplicated in the like clauses, but that shouldn't matter. Have i missed something?

---

### Fixed it!

The group_concat() functions i used caused the query to only return one result, and concatenate the categories and category_id's for all movies. I just removed the group_concat()'s and it works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `GROUP_CONCAT` which is an aggregate function and collapses your results into one.

Add a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT movies . * , GROUP_CONCAT( categories.name ) AS categories, GROUP_CONCAT( categories.id ) AS categories_id
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN movies_categories ON ( movies.id = movies_categories.movie_id ) 
LEFT JOIN categories ON ( movies_categories.category_id = categories.id ) 
WHERE movies.movie_title LIKE  '%surfer%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%date%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%never%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%back%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%down%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%surfer%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%soul%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%the%'
OR movies.movie_title LIKE  '%transporter%'
GROUP BY
        movies.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Also, if your `movies` table is `MyISAM`, you can run this:

```
SELECT  movies.*,
        GROUP_CONCAT(categories.name) AS categories,
        GROUP_CONCAT(categories.id) AS categories_id
FROM    movies
LEFT JOIN
        movies_categories
ON      movies_categories.movie_id = movies.id
LEFT JOIN
        categories
ON      categories.id = movies_categories.category_id 
WHERE   MATCH(movie_title) AGAINST ("never back down" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY
        movies.id
LIMIT  0, 30
```

This query will run much faster if you create a `FULLTEXT` index:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fx_movies_title ON movies (movie_title)
```

Comment: You wrote this while i was editing my answer with the solution, hehe. Thanks though, marked as accepted.

Comment: Fulltext sounds good. Will i have to run the last query to index the database on a regular basis or only once? If only once then i'll definately go for it. And oh, in the last query you wrote "fx_movies_title", what does that stand for? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if i'm spamming the comments now, but i'm getting a syntax error using your code. Here's my complete query: [link](http://pastebin.com/Be7EWm2c)

Comment: @qwerty: `fx_movies_title` is the index name, pick any index name you like. No, you will have to index the table only once, the index will be maintained by the db after that. Your link does not contain the error message you're getting. Also, remove `DISTINCT` from the query, you don't need it since `movies.id` is a `PK` and you're grouping on it.

Comment: @qwerty: you missed the `WHERE` clause.